# nx affected not working with --base and --head

Tags: nrwl-nx

I'm trying to run `nx affected:build` inside a GitHub `push` action, yet I'm getting the `No projects with build were run` (this happens against lint/test/build). I know for a fact that projects are affected b/c I run `nx affected:build` on them prior to making a PR and the build runs.

At first I suspected it might be because I was operating in the Github `push` action. So I tried using various `--base` and `--head` parameters, but nothing worked.

Then I tried running these same commands locally, and `nx affected:build` still produced nothing, even though `git diff` clearly showed that a project was affected. It's only until I run `nx affected:build ==base=<branch>` that the affected project will be built.

Eg:

```
// Doesn't work, even though there is a diff.
nx affected:build --base=197458c645479844fc235ea09b5ae12048b7fa35 --head=da8fad48d67bd8a0c59b8fbecba0bdf7c90fdf6e

// Works
nx affected:build --base=develop
```

What am I missing here? Why can't I supply `--base` and `--head` parameters to specify the exact commits to run `nx affected` against?

Answer (score 2):

It seems I had `base` and `head` backwards:

```
--base  Base of the current branch (usually master)
--head  Latest commit of the current branch (usually HEAD)
```

When I switched the SHAs around, `nx affected` produced the desired outcome.

Answer (score 0):

try checking the commit message:

- if the first letter should be a capital letter
- no spaces before the commit message

Sometimes the commit needs to be written in a specific way so it can be accepted and you can push it. Hope this helps

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Your command should be like below, it misses the double quote

```
nx affected:build --base="197458c645479844fc235ea09b5ae12048b7fa35" --head="da8fad48d67bd8a0c59b8fbecba0bdf7c90fdf6e"
```